# Javascript - Call function after last timeout in a loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, reactjs, timeout

I currently have a loop that animates HTML elements every second, and after the last animation is completed, I want to accept user input:

```
playSequence(currentLevel) {
  console.log("playing level " + currentLevel)
  for (var q = 0; q < currentLevel; q++) {
    (function(q) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var active = '#' + sequence[q].toString(); //the div currently being animated
        console.log(active);
        var currentColor = $(active).css('background-color');
        var newColor = currentColor.replace("0.6", "1.0");

        $(active).animate({
          backgroundColor: newColor
        }, 100, function() {}).delay(900).animate({
        backgroundColor: currentColor
        }, 100, function() {
        if (q === (currentLevel - 1)) {
          console.log("done"); //this runs
          this.getInput(1, currentLevel); //this does not
        }
      });

     }, 1000 * q)
   }(q));
 }    
}
```

After the last animation, "done" is printed, but getInput isn't called, as the console.log at the beginning of the function doesn't print.

Why doesn't it run after the last timer is finished, even though the console.log above it does?

However, if I move getInput like this,

```
playSequence(currentLevel) {
  console.log("playing level " + currentLevel)
  for (var q = 0; q < currentLevel; q++) {
    (function(q) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var active = '#' + sequence[q].toString(); //the div currently being animated
        console.log(active);
        var currentColor = $(active).css('background-color');
        var newColor = currentColor.replace("0.6", "1.0");

        $(active).animate({
          backgroundColor: newColor
        }, 100, function() {}).delay(900).animate({
        backgroundColor: currentColor
        }, 100, function() {
        if (q === (currentLevel - 1)) {
          console.log("done"); //this runs

        }
      });

     }, 1000 * q)
   }(q));
 }
this.getInput(1, currentLevel); //this runs   
}
```

Then getInput does run, however it doesn't work as I want because it runs before the animations have completed since it runs outside the scope of the timeOut.

Note: this is contained within a React class, and getInput isn't a method inside of playSequence, they're both within a class called "Game"

Comment: It is a matter of context, in the first example `this` refers to the `active` element and in the second it refers to the `playSequence` function's context.

Comment: this is contained within a React class, and getInput isn't a method inside of playSequence, they're both within a class called "Game"

Comment: If you do `var t = this;` above all of your Anonymous functions you can use `t.getInput()` in there.

Comment: @PHPglue thank you, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PHPGlue's comment works, leaving their answer in case anyone stumbles upon it in the future:

> If you do var t = this; above all of your Anonymous functions you can use t.getInput() in there

Comment: I removed "this is window in the Anonymous function." from comment after realizing this is jQuery so that function is called in some other context. You'll get context binding soon, I hope.